# Append / Insert Data Into BigQuery Table Using R's bigrquery Library

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

Question is straightforward. I have the following code:

```
# authenticate
bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '/Users/me/restofthepath/bigquery-credentials.json')

# set my project ID and dataset name
project_id <- 'mygreatprojectid'
dataset_name <- 'static'

# how i normally create a new table
players_table = bq_table(project = project_id, dataset = dataset_name, table = 'players')
bq_table_create(x = players_table, fields = as_bq_fields(players_df))
bq_table_upload(x = players_table, values = players_df)
```

Here, `players_df` is a dataframe of player statistics already computed in R. The following code works successfully, creating a new table. However, if I have more players that I'd like to append to the table, I am struggling. I have tried the following:

```
bq_table_upload(x = players_table, values = players_df_2)
```

...where `players_df_2` is another dataframe with more player statistics... However, this returns the error `Error: Already Exists: Table mygreatprojectid:static.players [duplicate]`

Any thoughts on how to do this, preferably without having to delete + recreate the table? Thanks!!

**EDIT**: It looks like [bq_table_patch](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/pull/304) exists, however this appears to be for adding new fields/columns, not for appending new rows...

Answer (score 19):

You need to set the `WRITE_DISPOSITION` and `CREATE_DISPOSITION`, for example:

```
bq_table_upload(x=players_table, values= players_df_2, create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED', write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')
```